# mocking web service

Tags: java, easymock, jmock

I would like to mock a web service call to test my code.
The following is a code snippet of which I want to mock. 
I would like to test callWebService() method. I want a way to create my own HttpResponse when callRestClientService(criteria) is called. I tried using JMock and EasyMock but unable to get the desired result. At the first instance I believe that I will not be able to mock or create my own HttpResponse.

Even if I am not able to mock the gateway call, I already have a local server to which I can make call to, but I would have to mock the reply sent back by the server to test different scenarios.

Can anyone help me with this....
Thanks!!

```
public class RestClientServiceResponse
{
    public HttpResponse callRestClientService(final RestClientServiceCriteria criteria) throws IOException
    {
        final HttpUriRequest request = buildHttpUriRequest(criteria);
        return executeRestClientServiceCall(request);
    }

    public HttpResponse executeRestClientServiceCall(final HttpUriRequest request) throws IOException
    {
        final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);

        return httpResponse;
    }
}


public class CallWebService
{
    public void callWebService()
    {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try
        {
            httpResponse = restClient.callRestClientService(criteria);
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say " I tried using JMock and EasyMock but unable to get the desired result", could you post what you've tried? To give us something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, just use something like an embedded [Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty) or [Simple HTTP](http://www.simpleframework.org/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php) server. I tend to use Simple because it has generally better documentation. You can very easily set it to return whatever you want for a test. Depending on the complexity you need, you can even embed a mock inside the server, letting you perform normal mocking operations on the mock, which are translated into verifying HTTP requests and preparing HTTP responses.

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI is a open source tool created to test web services and it supports service mocking very well. Go through [this tutorial](http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/mock-services/1-Creating-a-MockService.html) on how to do it.